# Using the twitter API and Python to obatain retweeter's id

Tags: python, api, twitter, scripting

I have an issue that has been bothering for a while now, and which I have tried really hard to fix but have found no solution.
So I'm doing an internship doing research on complex networks, nothing business-oriented, it's mostly physics and network theory research that they are doing. 
So what I'm doing is writing scripts for them to obtain data from twitter and tumblr (such as friend lists, and retweets) and then then graphing the user-to-user relations.

Anyways, going straight to my problem, I have already written my script pretty much, mainly using the twitter-python wrapper. However, none of the wrappers for python has any way of using the GET statuses/retweets/:id which returns the 100 first retweeter's ids. I've looked through all different twitter libraries for python and could not find anything.
I found tweety for MATLAB but I'm using Ubuntu and it hasn't been easy to obtain.

So my question is, how can I implement this API myself, without a wrapper? is there any wrapper, even in another language that you guys would know allows me to do this? I wouldn't mind getting the retweet information in a file and then using my python script to go over it and get the information I need.

Thank you very much!
This is the resource I wanna use:
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/retweets/%3Aid

EDIT:
So with tweepy this is what I'm trying to do

```
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)

tweet = auth.retweets(TWEET_ID)

print json.dumps(tweet, indent=1)
```

Comment: I'm just basically trying to make this:
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/retweets/%3Aid

work on python, even better if with the trim_user parameter set to 1 or t

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like [tweepy](http://pythonhosted.org/tweepy/html/index.html) should work for you. See [docs](http://pythonhosted.org/tweepy/html/api.html?highlight=retweet#API.retweets) and [source](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/blob/master/tweepy/api.py#L124).

Example:

```
import tweepy

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(key, secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth)

public_tweets = api.search("stackoverflow")
for tweet in public_tweets:
    print api.retweets(tweet.id)
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: thank you for your reply. This however prints retweeted tweets from a search. What I'm trying to do is use the twitter API to insert a tweet ID and receive the user ID of the first 100 people that retweeted that tweet. This is the part of the API that allows this:
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/retweets/%3Aid
But tweepy doesn't offer me any tool to use this :/
thank you :)

Comment: Right, thank you. What if you call `update_status` to post a tweet and then get users from the list of `retweets`?

Comment: But I'm not trying to see the people who retweet (I'd probably not even get to 100 rts) I want this to work for any twitter ID I insert. Twitter says that the resource URL is https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/retweets/:id.json 
So how do I do it so I can insert any id in its place and use the oAuth on it (the oAuth with twitter-python is great for me so far at least)

Comment: If I'm correctly understanding you, tweepy does exactly this call for `/statuses/retweets/:id.json`: https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/blob/master/tweepy/api.py#L124.

Comment: Oooh I hadn't seen that! So how could I use this, just do t = oAuth and then t.retweets(TWEET_ID) ?

Comment: Yup, as I've used in the code provided. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: I haven't been able to do the OAuth dance, most tutorials seem to be outdated for that

Comment: Hm, what kind of problems do you have? You should have `consumer key`, `consumer secret`, `access token` and `access token secret`, which you can find in your application settings on dev.twitter.com. Additionally, your app should have an ability to post tweets.

Comment: ok, I did the short OAuth and it works, now how do I use that class you pointed me to? this is what I'm trying:
Edit: I put the code on the original question

thanks a lot btw!

Comment: You should first get instance of tweepy api: `api = tweepy.API(auth)`, then try `tweet = api.retweets(TWEET_ID)`, then `print json.dumps(tweet, indent=1)`.

Comment: I had just realized that!
So I did that and I get this error:
TypeError: <tweepy.models.Status object at 0x29ed550> is not JSON serializable
So I tried to do a "print tweet"

Comment: and i get this:
[<tweepy.models.Status object at 0x2286550>, <tweepy.models.Status object at 0x2286590>, <tweepy.models.Status object at 0x2286690>, <tweepy.models.Status object at 0x22a39d0>, <tweepy.models.Status object at 0x22a3b10>, <tweepy.models.Status object at 0x22a3c10>, <tweepy.models.Status object at 0x22a3d50>, <tweepy.models.Status object at 0x22a3e50>, <tweepy.models.Status object at 0x22a3f50>]

Comment: I think each one of those is a different status? If I play around with the count parameter I get more or less of those objects

Comment: there's the same problem with the code you originally posted. How do I use this output, the documentation says the payload type is "status," how do I use them?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured it out,
when doing the loop instead of printing out the retweet, I printed out the retweets.uset.screen_name
Very silly of me, thank you all for the help