# Tweepy returning empty lists in API.retweets() method

Tags: python, python-3.x, twitter, tweepy, tweets

I want to use either [retweets](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/retweets/%3Aid) or [retweeters](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/retweeters/ids) endpoints to create a csv of users and their retweeters.
Tweepy has a support for retweets method using `API.retweets()` documented [here](http://docs.tweepy.org/en/v3.5.0/api.html#API.retweets). I wrote the code exactly like shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16297041/2650427), but all I am getting is empty list for every tweet. Why is that happening?

Comment: Are you asking for retweets in a tweet that has retweets? You get any error with auth?

Comment: @YábirGarcia I am asking for the retweeters (that is, id of the retweeter) of a particular tweet. I am getting no errors. I am just getting empty list.

Answer (score 0):

The code in the answer to the other question makes a query with the keyword `stackoverflow` and then for each tweet It prints the retweets using the tweepy api function `retweets`.

Well, it makes the search but you get an empty list because the tweets that it gets have no retweets made. You can check this by printing the id and looking for this tweet. You will see how it has no retweets. The results for the query are those in the url `https://twitter.com/search?f=tweets&vertical=default&q=stackoverflow&src=typd`

You can check with another tweet that have retweets how `api.retweets(id_of_tweet)` will return the list with the retweets. ex: `print(api.retweets(683242988806475776))`

Comment: Thanks for answering. But I checked the tweet I was trying to get retweeters of and the `retweet_count` of that tweet was not 0. Anyway, I tried the same thing using the module `twython` and I am getting the required results.